# Oracle SQL Script to extract emergency and family contact details

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a script to extract emergency contact details and also if the contact is a dependent:

for example, I'd like to report on employees who have

1. an emergency contact
2. a family dependent contact
3. both 1 and 2

So far, the script I have, is as follows:

```
select distinct
emp.employee_number
, emp.person_id
, emp.full_name
, emer_cont.full_name "EMER_CONT"
, em_pcr.contact_type "Emer Cont"
, em_pcr.primary_contact_flag "Emer Primary"
, emer_cont.person_id
, contact.full_name "CONTACT"
, cont_pcr.contact_type "Cont Type"
, cont_pcr.primary_contact_flag "Cont Primary"
, contact.person_id
from
apps.per_all_people_f emp,
apps.per_all_people_f emer_cont,
apps.per_all_people_f contact,
apps.per_contact_relationships em_pcr,
apps.per_contact_relationships cont_pcr
where 1=1
and emp.current_employee_flag = 'Y'
and emp.person_id = em_pcr.person_id
and emp.person_id = cont_pcr.person_id
and emer_cont.person_id = em_pcr.contact_person_id(+)
and contact.person_id = cont_pcr.contact_person_id(+)
and em_pcr.contact_type = 'EMRG'
and cont_pcr.contact_type NOT in ('EMRG')
```

So, I've got the 3 per_all_people_f tables aliased, emp for the employee, contact for the family contact, and emer_cont for the emergency contact.

All works well, if the emergency contact is also a family contact, however I'm finding that if the person a is an emergency contact, then that info is reported, however its then linked to person b as a family contact.

Would anyone have any thoughts on how the script needs to be changed, so that if an employee has a family contact, the emergency contact details are reported as blank, and if an employee has an emergency contact, but no family, so that the family contact details are blank?

Thanks in advance for any/all help!
Tony

Comment: First, I would change to contemporary join logic. From A join B on a.column = b.column

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Tryed to reconstruct the data beneath your SQL. The WITH clause creating the cte-s "people" and "contacts" is not part of the answer but my guess of the data you are dealing with. As being said - two tables (cte-s) were created.

1. people

```sql
WITH
    people AS
        (
            Select 101 "EMP_NUMBER", '100001' "PERSON_ID", 'John Duffy'     "FULL_NAME", 'Y' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 102 "EMP_NUMBER", '100002' "PERSON_ID", 'Anne Freadman'  "FULL_NAME", 'Y' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 103 "EMP_NUMBER", '100003' "PERSON_ID", 'Bob Staines'    "FULL_NAME", 'Y' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 104 "EMP_NUMBER", '100004' "PERSON_ID", 'Mark Stevens'   "FULL_NAME", 'Y' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 105 "EMP_NUMBER", '100005' "PERSON_ID", 'Alice Smith'    "FULL_NAME", 'Y' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 106 "EMP_NUMBER", '100006' "PERSON_ID", 'Richard Fox'    "FULL_NAME", 'Y' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 107 "EMP_NUMBER", '100007' "PERSON_ID", 'Evan Rostow'    "FULL_NAME", 'Y' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 108 "EMP_NUMBER", '100008' "PERSON_ID", 'Jamey Robins'   "FULL_NAME", 'Y' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 109 "EMP_NUMBER", '100009' "PERSON_ID", 'Kate Hudson'    "FULL_NAME", 'Y' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 911 "EMP_NUMBER", '911001' "PERSON_ID", 'Jakob ...'      "FULL_NAME", 'N' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 911 "EMP_NUMBER", '911002' "PERSON_ID", 'Michael ...'    "FULL_NAME", 'N' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 911 "EMP_NUMBER", '911003' "PERSON_ID", 'Jane ...'       "FULL_NAME", 'N' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 888 "EMP_NUMBER", '888001' "PERSON_ID", 'Alan ...'       "FULL_NAME", 'N' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 911 "EMP_NUMBER", '911004' "PERSON_ID", 'Maria ...'      "FULL_NAME", 'N' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 888 "EMP_NUMBER", '888002' "PERSON_ID", 'Alex ...'       "FULL_NAME", 'N' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select 888 "EMP_NUMBER", '888003' "PERSON_ID", 'Julian ...'     "FULL_NAME", 'N' "CURR_EMPL_FLAG" From Dual 
        ),
--  
--  Table PEOPLE
--  
--  EMP_NUMBER PERSON_ID FULL_NAME     CURR_EMPL_FLAG
--  ---------- --------- ------------- --------------
--         101 100001    John Duffy    Y              
--         102 100002    Anne Freadman Y              
--         103 100003    Bob Staines   Y              
--         104 100004    Mark Stevens  Y              
--         105 100005    Alice Smith   Y              
--         106 100006    Richard Fox   Y              
--         107 100007    Evan Rostow   Y              
--         108 100008    Jamey Robins  Y              
--         109 100009    Kate Hudson   Y              
--         911 911001    Jakob ...     N              
--         911 911002    Michael ...   N              
--         911 911003    Jane ...      N              
--         888 888001    Alan ...      N              
--         911 911004    Maria ...     N              
--         888 888002    Alex ...      N              
--         888 888003    Julian ...    N
```

2. contacts

```sql
    contacts AS
        (
            Select '100001' "PERSON_ID", '911004' "CONTACT_ID", 'EMRG' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Y' "PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select '100001' "PERSON_ID", '888001' "CONTACT_ID", 'FMLY' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'N' "PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select '100003' "PERSON_ID", '888002' "CONTACT_ID", 'FMLY' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Y' "PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select '100005' "PERSON_ID", '911001' "CONTACT_ID", 'EMRG' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Y' "PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select '100006' "PERSON_ID", '911002' "CONTACT_ID", 'EMRG' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Y' "PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select '100008' "PERSON_ID", '911003' "CONTACT_ID", 'EMRG' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Y' "PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG" From Dual Union All
            Select '100009' "PERSON_ID", '888003' "CONTACT_ID", 'FMLY' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Y' "PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG" From Dual 
        )
--          
--  Table CONTACTS  
--  
--  PERSON_ID CONTACT_ID CONTACT_TYPE PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG
--  --------- ---------- ------------ --------------------
--  100001    911004     EMRG         Y                    
--  100001    888001     FMLY         N                    
--  100003    888002     FMLY         Y                    
--  100005    911001     EMRG         Y                    
--  100006    911002     EMRG         Y                    
--  100008    911003     EMRG         Y                    
--  100009    888003     FMLY         Y
```

Now, if the general picture was guessed well enough there is several possibilities to get your expected result (which I am guessing too). There will be two of them in this answer.

**Option one**

- select contact's data (added descriptive data) with basic employee data who the contacts belong to
- number of rows returned = total number of current employee's contacts

```sql
SELECT
    p.EMP_NUMBER "EMP_NUMBER",
    p.PERSON_ID "PERSON_ID",
    p.FULL_NAME "FULL_NAME",
    c.CONTACT_ID "CONTACT_ID",
    c.CONTACT_TYPE "CONTACT_TYPE",
    c.PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG "PRIMARY",
    CASE WHEN c.PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG = 'Y' THEN 'Primary' ELSE 'Secundary' END "CONTACT", 
    CASE WHEN c.CONTACT_TYPE = 'EMRG' THEN cnt.FULL_NAME ELSE Null END "EMGR_CONTACT_NAME",
    CASE WHEN c.CONTACT_TYPE = 'FMLY' THEN cnt.FULL_NAME ELSE Null END "FMLY_CONTACT_NAME"
FROM
    people p
LEFT JOIN
    contacts c ON(c.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID)
INNER JOIN 
    people cnt ON(cnt.PERSON_ID = c.CONTACT_ID)
WHERE
    p.CURR_EMPL_FLAG = 'Y'
ORDER BY
    p.EMP_NUMBER

--  
--  R e s u l t
--
--  EMP_NUMBER PERSON_ID FULL_NAME     CONTACT_ID CONTACT_TYPE PRIMARY CONTACT   EMGR_CONTACT_NAME FMLY_CONTACT_NAME
--  ---------- --------- ------------- ---------- ------------ ------- --------- ----------------- -----------------
--         101 100001    John Duffy    888001     FMLY         N       Secundary                   Alan ...          
--         101 100001    John Duffy    911004     EMRG         Y       Primary   Maria ...                           
--         103 100003    Bob Staines   888002     FMLY         Y       Primary                     Alex ...          
--         105 100005    Alice Smith   911001     EMRG         Y       Primary   Jakob ...                           
--         106 100006    Richard Fox   911002     EMRG         Y       Primary   Michael ...                         
--         108 100008    Jamey Robins  911003     EMRG         Y       Primary   Jane ...                            
--         109 100009    Kate Hudson   888003     FMLY         Y       Primary                     Julian ...
```

**Option two**

- select aggregated employee's and contact's data with some descriptive column names
- number of rows returned = total number of current employees having at least one contact

```sql
SELECT
    p.EMP_NUMBER "EMP_NUMBER",
    p.PERSON_ID "PERSON_ID",
    p.FULL_NAME "FULL_NAME",
    Max(CASE WHEN c.PRIMARY_CONTACT_FLAG  = 'Y' THEN c.CONTACT_TYPE ELSE Null END) "PRIMARY_TYPE",
    Max(CASE WHEN c.CONTACT_TYPE = 'EMRG' THEN c.CONTACT_ID ELSE Null END) "EMRG_CONTACT_ID",
    Max(CASE WHEN c.CONTACT_TYPE = 'EMRG' THEN cnt.FULL_NAME ELSE Null END) "EMRG_CONTACT_NAME",
    Max(CASE WHEN c.CONTACT_TYPE = 'FMLY' THEN c.CONTACT_ID ELSE Null END) "FMLY_CONTACT_ID",
    Max(CASE WHEN c.CONTACT_TYPE = 'FMLY' THEN cnt.FULL_NAME ELSE Null END) "FMLY_CONTACT_NAME"
FROM
    people p
LEFT JOIN
    contacts c ON(c.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID)
INNER JOIN 
    people cnt ON(cnt.PERSON_ID = c.CONTACT_ID)
WHERE
    p.CURR_EMPL_FLAG = 'Y'
GROUP BY
    p.EMP_NUMBER, p.PERSON_ID, p.FULL_NAME
ORDER BY
    p.EMP_NUMBER
--  
--  R e s u l t
--
--  EMP_NUMBER PERSON_ID FULL_NAME     PRIMARY_TYPE EMRG_CONTACT_ID EMRG_CONTACT_NAME FMLY_CONTACT_ID FMLY_CONTACT_NAME
--  ---------- --------- ------------- ------------ --------------- ----------------- --------------- -----------------
--         101 100001    John Duffy    EMRG         911004          Maria ...         888001          Alan ...          
--         103 100003    Bob Staines   FMLY         Null            Null              888002          Alex ...          
--         105 100005    Alice Smith   EMRG         911001          Jakob ...         Null            Null                      
--         106 100006    Richard Fox   EMRG         911002          Michael ...       Null            Null                      
--         108 100008    Jamey Robins  EMRG         911003          Jane ...          Null            Null                      
--         109 100009    Kate Hudson   FMLY         Null            Null              888003          Julian ...
```

There are some other options to get different outcomes. Hopefully, this will be good enough to you to, if not solve the problem, then, at least, to help you consider  the logic behind it. Once more, the structure of the data in the answer is just my best  guess and the same is with these two resulting options. Regards...